# spotlight finds "anaconda-navigator" but `conda` has been uninstalled

Tags: spotlight, macos, alias

**CLARIFICATION**.

I am not trying to use `conda`, much less reinstall it.  My question is about a behaviour that I don't understand.

**THE BEHAVIOUR**.

Some time ago I (must have) uninstalled `conda`, and indeed:

```bsh
conda list
bash: conda: command not found
```

Now, when I start typing "anaconda" in spotlight, it finds "anaconda-navigator".  Not surprisingly, when I press enter, it gives me a "The application “Anaconda-Navigator” can’t be opened."

This shows that something has been left behind during the (manual) uninstall, but that is another issue.

**MY QUESTION**.

Where does spotlight find this `anaconda-navigator`?

Comment: You can verify from Terminal: ```conda list``` should list all packages available, and, if it is not listed, just ```conda install anaconda-navigator``` since that is a python application.

Comment: I uninstalled, so that `conda list` returns `bash: conda: command not found`.  I am clarifying in my question that I am not trying to use `conda`, in fact I want to completely remove it from my system.

Comment: Somewhat off topic, but I'm having the opposite problem: Spotlight doesn't see Anaconda.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Finder → Applications and find Anaconda-Navigator.app. It should be an alias.  Right click on it and click on "Show original" .

For proper uninstall

> Anaconda-Clean must be run before simple remove.
>    Install the
>   Anaconda-Clean package from Anaconda Prompt (terminal on Linux or
>   macOS):
>
> `conda install anaconda-clean`.
>
> In the same window, run one of these commands:
>
> Remove all Anaconda-related files and directories with a confirmation
>   prompt before deleting each one:
>
> `anaconda-clean`
>
> Or, remove all Anaconda-related files and directories
>   without being prompted to delete each one:
>
> `anaconda-clean --yes`
>
> Anaconda-Clean creates a backup of all files and
>   directories that might be removed in a folder named `.anaconda_backup`
>   in your home directory. Also note that Anaconda-Clean leaves your data
>   files in the AnacondaProjects directory untouched. After using
>   Anaconda-Clean

delete the folder where the installation previously was. It should be named `anaconda3` or `anaconda2` etc.,

https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall/

But since you don't have `conda`, seen by "command not found" deleting the remnant files can be done using apps like EasyFind.

Comment: Why did I not think of looking via Finder?  At any rate, I found `Anaconda-Navigator.app`, right-clicked and selected "Show original", and it gave me a message that it could not open it (I should have taken a precise note of it.). It appeared to be a link/alias(?), so I deleted it.  Unfortunately the problem seems to persist: spotlight still finds 'anaconda-navigator'...  Do I need to restart to see changes?

Comment: Use easyfind app and scan your laptop

Comment: I thought I would try with a `bash` command, `find /* -name "*anaconda-navigator.app*"` but it doesn't return anything (other than a number of `Operation not permitted`).  Does `easyfind` do anything that the `bash` command `find` cannot?

Comment: I just find all the listing, "revealing in Finder" and deleting made easier.